# Pegar quantidade de entradas dentro do JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

Olá, estou tendo dificuldades para pegar o número de entradas que é feito pelo usuário para depois utilizá-los.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int n, s = 0, p, i, c, m;
    do {
      n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "<html>Informe um número: <br><em>(Valor 0 interrompe)</em></html>"));
      s += n;
    } while (n != 0);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Resultado: <hr><br>" +
    "Soma de Valores: " + s + "<br>Total de Pares:" +
    "<br>Total de Ímpares:" + "<br>Acima de 100:" +
    "<br>Média de Valores: </html>");

}
```

Explicação das variáveis

```
n -> número informado
s -> soma dos números
p -> valores pares
i -> valores ímpares
c -> números acima de 100
m -> média
```

Certo, o problema seria: Como eu faço pra pegar o número de entradas que o usuário deu?

Por exemplo, ele usa as seguintes entradas: **2, 12, 31, 47, 132, 0**;

Ou seja, pra eu fazer a média eu deveria pegar o total e dividir pelo número de entradas:

**224** (soma) **/ 5** (número de entradas, excluindo o 0)

Como eu faço pra ele contar o número de entradas pra usar?

Comment: São duas perguntas bem diferentes juntas, recomendo separá-las, até porque a segunda está meio confusa. Talvez separando ela em uma nova você consiga explicar melhor sem tornar a pergunta ampla.

Comment: Certo, corrigi a pergunta e deixei o tema principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das possíveis soluções, pensando de forma simplista, seria adicionar um contador e checar se n é igual a 0, se não for, incrementa:

```
int n, s = 0, p, i, c, m, contador = 0;

do {
  n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "<html>Informe um número: <br><em>(Valor 0 interrompe)</em></html>"));
  s += n;

  if(n != 0){
     contador++;
  }

} while (n != 0);
```

Comment: Acabei utilizando uma variável **e** e adicionei um **e++;** ao while. Coloquei também como valor inicial -1, assim quando o usuário colocar o 0 não irá ter "constar" o 0.

Answer (score -1):

Acabei desenvolvendo o programa todo deste modo:

```
    int n, s = 0, p = -1, i = 0, c = 0, m = -1, e = -1;
    do {
      n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "<html>Informe um número: <br><em>(Valor 0 interrompe)</em></html>"));
      s += n;
      m++;
      e++;
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
          p++;
    } else {
          i++;    
      }
      if (n >= 100){
          c++;
      }
    } while (n != 0);
    int media = s / m;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Resultado: <hr><br>" + "Número de Entradas: " +
            e + "<br>Soma de Valores: " + s + "<br>Total de Pares: " + p + "<br>Total de Ímpares: " +
            i + "<br>Acima de 100: " + c + "<br>Média de Valores: " + media + "</html>");
```

Caso tenha maneiras mais simples, por favor, corrijam.

Comment: Se m é seu contador, ele está errado, começar com -1 não vai retornar o número correto de entradas, e consequentemente sua media também ficará errada. Veja a resposta que eu fiz abaixo.

Comment: Na verdade ele não vai "zerar" o contador quando o usuário coloca o 0 pra interromper o programa?

Comment: Não, ele vai contar com um número a menos, sua media vai sempre ficar errada. Se você quer todas as entradas, menos zero, veja como eu fiz a validação na resposta. Sem contar que essa divisão tem sério risco de soltar um `aritmethicexception`, pois se a segunda entrada for zero, seu contador também será zero e seu programa tentará fazer uma divisão impossivel.